# "The volume for a file has been externally altered ..." and setting file sizes on write to NFS from Windows

Tags: windows, nfs, hdfs

I have set up NFS access to HDFS.

I can connect to the default root share from both Windows and Linux clients and all clients can read from the share. Writing from the Linux client is also ok.

When I try to copy a file to the share from a Windows Server 2012 R2 client I get an error stating

> The volume for a file has been externally altered so that the opened file is no longer valid.

The log in the NFS server contains

> ERROR org.apache.hdfs.nfs.nfs3: Setting file size is not supported when creating file.

Which sounds reasonable given that HDFS is an append only file system.

Based on some web searching a similar problem would appear to exist for some CD/DVD writing wrappers that expose devices and it looks like there are ways to solve those.

Is there a way that I can stop Windows trying to set the file size as it creates the files on this particular device - or maybe all NFS mounts on the system?